# How to make custom search functions

Tags: django

How can i make a custom search function in django admin. I want to search all fields of the database tables and to find and retrieve the matches.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take an example of custom `User` models with below fields,

**app_name/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now the admin for this models would be,

**app_name/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app_name.models import User

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = User._meta.get_all_field_names()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

`User._meta.get_all_field_names()` will return you a `list` of all the fields of `User` model.

Comment: thanks... but I need to access other models fields of the app also.

Comment: @noble: You can do the same for other models also. I've just given a sample example of a `model`.

Comment: Thanks... but i have another problem . when am searching for female values it gives the correct answer, but for male vale it display male and female results